# S-sets (even though this title is too short)

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, perfect-numbers

I say a finite sequence of positive integers is 'autistic' if and only if the sum of the reciprocals of its elements is itself an element of the sequence. That way, the 'sequence' just made of the number 1 is autistic, but so is the sequence of the divisors of an even perfect number arranged in increasing order, as well as any permutation thereof. Are there other examples of autistic sequences ?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: title changed because of some comments.

Comment: These might be better described as "sets" rather than "sequences." And why have you used the word "autistic" to describe these sets?

Comment: Because in some sense they stay inside themselves.

Comment: (1,2,2) or (1,2,2,3,3,3) works. also perplexed by your choice of name.

Comment: okay, that makes sense, but are you 12 or something? glib jokes about autism are not very kind.

Comment: @djechlin, "aut" is a prefix that means "self", e.g. "auto".  The OP might not be a native English speaker, and trying to invent a suitable word.

Comment: Indeed, I'm French, and very probably autistic myself. That doesn't prevent me from having some humor and enjoying self-derision.

Comment: I'd still avoid using such terminology, especially if you wanted to write something about it. In any case, do you mean set? Because if you had an infinite sequence of $1$s, the sum of the reciprocals would be an infinite sum of $1$s. I think you mean a set.

Comment: Apart from that, I require the elements to be pairwise distinct, so indeed one might be better off speaking of sets. Still, I wonder whether, denoting by $m$ the considered sum of reciprocals, $m$ is the $m$-th element of the sequence obtained by arranging the elements of the set by increasing order.

Comment: @KevinLong: sets can be infinite and sequences can be finite. The OP wrote "finite sequence". The question is perfectly meaningful as written with "finite sequence", but there seems to be general agreement (even including the OP) that that was not what was intended.

Comment: How about *introverted* sequences (or sets)?

Comment: @Théophile: that's quite a good idea.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As tomi pointed out in the comments, there's nothing about the sequence that you need to keep in order, so it's more basic to just talk about sets.

Any [Egyptian fraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egyptian_fraction) sequence can be indefinitely prolonged, so we can write, for instance,

\begin{align}
2 & = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2} \\
  & = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{6} \\
  & = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{42} \\
  & = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{7}+\frac{1}{43}+\frac{1}{1806}
\end{align}

or alternatively

$$
2 = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{12}+\frac{1}{6}
$$

by expanding $1/3$, and that can extend indefinitely as well.  That means that the sets $\{1, 2, 3, 6\}, \{1, 2, 3, 7, 42\}, \{1, 2, 3, 7, 43, 1806\}, \{1, 2, 4, 6, 12\}$ (among an infinity of others) all satisfy the condition.

---

ETA: If we allow multisets, then $\{1, 2, 2\}$, and the like, also work.

Comment: Thank you. Since my terminology worries some people here, I'll speak of S-sets, leaving the choice of the interpretation to the reader, whether it stands for 'Self', 'Sylvain', Satisfying' or some four letter word one shouldn't write according to them.

Answer (score 5):

Do the sequences have to increase in order? Otherwise there are surely infinitely many (e.g. 1, 2, 2)

For example, to make the sequence out of any integer $n$ you just need $n^2$ of $n$.

Comment: That's a comment, not an answer.

Comment: That's a criticism, not a suggestion.

Comment: I think the definition has to be clearer. I expect the OP's intention was for there to be no repeated members of the set, which would exclude sets like the one you have suggested.

Comment: I know, but apparently I need 50 reputation to comment >.>

Comment: @DanielCastle: fair enough. I upvoted your answer to help you on your way.

Comment: @vadim123: duh?